# io-ts parse array of Eithers/Validations

Tags: typescript, validation, parsing, fp-ts

I'm trying to parse an API response that returns an array of users. I've found that even if one element in the array fails the validation, the whole codec returns an error. I'd prefer the errors to stay inside the array so I could have something like `Array<Either<E, User>>`. The response from my API looks something like this

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "name": "Jo Smith",
            "email": "jo@jo.jo",
            "preferredName": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Robert",
            "email": "rob@rob.rob",
            "preferredName": "Rob"
        }
    ]
}
```

or

```json
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "Something went wrong"
}
```

So here's my codec

```
import * as t from "io-ts";

const userV = t.type({
    name: t.string,
    email: t.string,
    preferredName: t.union([t.string, null]),
});

const successV = t.type({
    success: t.literal(true),
    result: t.array(userV),
});

const errorV = t.type({
    success: t.literal(false),
    error: t.string,
});

const responseV = t.union([successV, errorV]);
```

Now, if for some reason, we receive a single user with null for email, the whole response fails. What if I wanted to list the correctly parsed users and display an error message just for the erroneous user in my UI? The obvious (naive?) way is to make all properties nullable but is there a better way? I've also considered parsing the response in two steps by first returning a `t.array(t.unknown)` but I'm not exactly sure how that might look like

Comment: Did you try to use `option` in your `userV` object? `{email: option(t.string)}`

Comment: Where does `option` come from? Also, I do expect the validation to fail for that object, but not for the entire `responseV` to fail

Comment: Just write: io-ts option in google

Comment: from io-ts-types, got it. Doesn't help me though. I do want the validation to fail if a field is wrong (in my real life case, I have more fields that might fail). What I need is for just the single `User` object to fail leaving the other proper objects to remain. So I think I need `result` to be an array of Eithers rather than an array of objects filled with options

Comment: I wish I could help you more but I m not an expert in io-ts

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```js
import * as t from "io-ts";
import * as F from 'fp-ts/function'
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either'
import * as A from 'fp-ts/Array'

const users: unknown[] = [{
  name: 'badUser',
  email: null,
  preferredName: 'hey'
}, {
  name: 'goodUser',
  email: 'ihaveemail@mail.com',
  preferredName: 'okay'
}]

const result = F.pipe(
  users,
  A.map(userV.decode),
  A.separate
)
```

`A.separate` is a function that takes an `Array<Either<A, B>>` and returns an object where all the `Left`s are in the `left` field, and the `Right`s on the `right` field.

Comment: Unfortunately this only solves half the problem. The list of users is nested inside a network response (first snippet of code in my question). I've demonstrated the problem here:https://codesandbox.io/s/fp-ts-examples-forked-yxu9f?file=/src/index.ts. It does look like users should be a list of `These` but I don't know how to write such a decoder.
https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/These.ts.html